# C# Conditional Operator - How is this Wrong?

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong for the life of me. I've been using ?: throughout the life of my project but all of a sudden I keep being told "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used" yet if I copy and paste the exact same thing into another file.. I get no error like that.

true ? "1" : "1"; should be the most basic statement that works, correct? I mean it already does elsewhere so what could I be not understanding?

[image: Conditional Statement]

Comment: the compiler is creating an error because that expression is pointless, you're not doing anything with the value what does it do? change it to var pointlessNumber = true ? "1" : "1"

Comment: That is an expression, not a statement.

Comment: you need to assign the value to some variable

Comment: set something equal to that. var x = true ? "1" : "1";

Comment: @johnny5 That's a pointless string, not a pointless number. Pointless distinction, admittedly...

Comment: `true? "1": "1"`  is an expression that evaluates to a value (in this case to the value `"1"`.  Could you just put `"1"` in the code by itself?  No! it is just a value, not an instruction to the computer to do something. An expression, (which evaluates to a value) can be part of a statement, but it by itself cannot be entered as a statement. Just as you could not just put `sin(27.3)` in the code as an independent statement.

Comment: @EdPlunkett it's funny you mention that I was thinking of editing it to say pointlessString after I wrote it, but then I decided it was a pointless change for a pointless example

Comment: @CharlesBretana when you say sin(27.3) do you mean `Math.Sin(27.3)` because if you do, that is a valid statement, Sure it wouldn't do anything but it wouldn't generate an error

Comment: It is, as you believe, a correct conditional expression -- but the compiler won't let you use it without assigning its result to something. It just won't. Some languages will. This one won't. They made that decision in the design phase years ago, and that's just the way it is. Call it arbitrary, call it tyrannical, call it late for dinner -- it is what it is. Now you know. Think of it this way: If you were writing Perl, you could do this. *But then you'd be writing Perl.* Count your blessings.

Comment: @CharlesBretana "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used". A _call_ can be a statement. That the called function returns a type other than `void` doesn't preclude its use. Similarly, increment and decrement produce useful side effects even though they are expressions with values that are discarded.

Comment: @HABO, yes, calls to methods that return void can be made, and calls to methods that return something, but the where the return value is not used, are legal.  So my comment, in that scenario, is technically not correct. However, (as I'm sure you understand), unless the function has side effects, such usage is pointless.  My comment should have been written as "An expression which evaluates to a value,  (except for expressions which are calls to other methods), can be part of a statement, but it by itself cannot be entered as a statement."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say you are using conditional operator elsewhere & it is working fine perhaps you are using it in a way different than the screen capture you have shared. I say this because C# won't allow you to do it in the way you mentioned: i.e.

```
true ? "1" : "1";
```

***Think of it this way:*** Conditional operator is in essence an if-else.

```
if (true)
    "1"; //does not make sense, it appears to be string but the compiler needs to know what this is exactly
else
    "1"; //same comment as above
```

To summarize you need to assign that string "1" to a variable & then things would work fine.

```
string str = true ? "1" : "1";
```

Comment: Fantastic. That helps understand exactly what I wasn't understanding. Very much appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: What I'm originally doing is saying `serverColumn.Contains("primary") ? product.PrimaryProductServer = server : product.SecondaryProductServer = server` I don't know how to go to a new line in stackoverflow here... As far as the condition, I guess I can't do it the way I was wanting to.

Comment: Interesting. But in this case you'd have to go with a simple if-else